# How to add jQuery objects to the jQuery composite object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simply put: the jQuery object is a composite pattern. How do I add jQuery objects to it?

An example:

```
var e1 = $('#element1');
var e2 = $('#element2');
```

...

I know want to create a new jQuery object jq such that it is composed of e1 and e2. I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
var jq = $();
jq.addInjQueryObjects([e1, e2]);
jq.hide();
```

how do I do this?

By the way, I realize that I could have just selected #element1 AND #element2 to begin with, that's not what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var e1 = $('#element1');
var e2 = $('#element2');

var jq = $();
jq = jq.add(e1).add(e2);
jq.hide();
```

It returns a new jQuery object instead of modifying the original, so you need to overwrite the original if you want to reuse the same variable.

---

**EDIT:** Note that you can also [use `jQuery.merge()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/), which will modify the original, but you'll need to pass in an Array of the DOM elements instead of the jQuery objects.

```
var e1 = $('#element1');
var e2 = $('#element2');

var jq = $();
$.merge( jq, [e1[0], e2[0]] );
jq.hide();
​
```

Comment: jsfiddle showing this technique (for anyone looking at this in the future): http://jsfiddle.net/yjtEb/

Comment: **.add()** _always_ adds the elements in the same order as they appear on the page, and only **$.merge()** allows to add the elements in a different order.